# How to link my Gridview function to the GridView object

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am new to creating ASP.Net pages. I have a basic asp.net page with a `GridView` object, and I have written a `RowDataBound` Event to change the row colors based on a condition. I need some help on how to link my function/event to the acutal `GridView` object. Should the function/event be placed on the client side or server-side?

ps. Im using Visual Studio 2010, if there is a way to add functions to an object using the toolbar options that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RowDataBound event is handled on the server side. You can either have the event code/logic in the "code-behind" file, or you can add an inline script in your HTML file.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  

<script runat="server">  
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
    {   
       // logic here
    }  
</script>  

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head id="Head1" runat="server">  
    <title>GridView RowDataBound Event</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <div>  
        <h2 style="color:Navy">GridView OnRowDataBound</h2>  
        <asp:SqlDataSource   
            ID="SqlDataSource1"  
            runat="server"  
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"  
            SelectCommand="SELECT ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice FROM Products"  
            >  
        </asp:SqlDataSource>  
        <asp:GridView   
            ID="GridView1"  
            runat="server"  
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  
            ForeColor="AliceBlue"  
            BackColor="DarkSalmon"  
            BorderColor="Salmon"  
            HeaderStyle-BackColor="Crimson"  
            AllowPaging="true"  
            AutoGenerateColumns="true"  
            DataKeyNames="ProductID"  
            OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  
            >  
        </asp:GridView>          
    </div>  
    </form>  
</body>
```

It is important to note that the OnRowDataBound property must have the same name as your even method. For example `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"` has the same name as the event handler signature `GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)`.

For more info, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx).

Comment: Thanks alot, this helps. Also I like to mention on the server side I have a folder called "App_Code" on the directory where all other C# files are located. Could I also create a new C# file, place my row event/function and link my GridView on default.aspx to that?

Comment: Yeah I believe you could do that. You will want to update the src path inside your .aspx file <%@ Page.. src="CodeBehind.cs"  %>